# Is it the correct way to implement the javascript string length property?

Tags: javascript, string

I want to implement the JavaScript string inbuilt functions but i'm little confused with length property

Below is my implementation

```
function MyString(str){

    this.str=str;

    //properties
    this.length=0;

        if(typeof this.str[0]=='undefined')
            this.length=0;          

        else
            for (var i = 0; typeof this.str[i]!='undefined' ; i++) 
             this.length++;

        //tostring method
    this.toString=function(){
        if(typeof this.str == 'string')
            console.log(this.str);
        else
            console.log("cannot be converted to String") ;  

    }
}
```

Is this is the correct way to implement length property.Because it looks horrible for me !!.Or if i want to calculate length  only when user calls 'str.length' and still length should remain as a property ,how do i do that

An alternative i've done is like that but will be a function

```
this.length=function(this.str){
//length logic here
}
```

How can i implement  it in a better way but still length appears to be a property

Comment: The question is "WHY?" [str.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) will return the string's length

Comment: That was going to be my question.

Comment: you are reinventing the wheel

Comment: `'abc'.split('').length` will give string length but it'll not work if you're still to write code for array `length` property #mild_sarcasm :D

Comment: Are you by any chance solving exercises from Object Oriented JavaScript -- Stoyan Stefanov? If so, maybe you should trust your instincts and implement it as best as you can. You will thank yourself in the long run as you've "taught yourself how to fish". Otherwise, let me know and I can provide a URL for reference. (not being mean or anything) :)

Comment: yes I'm exactly trying to solve problems from " Object Oriented JavaScript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are confused about( i assume you are trying to create your own string object):

> 1. is it a better way of defining a property?
> 2. is there any alternative way? and
> 3. shall i put the logic for calculating the length inside a function and still use it as a property

If you have a property like `string.length` to build on your own, and you want to have some manipulations on it before it is initialized then you are doing it right.

A property will just be defined inside the constructor function, with all its initialization, like the way you have done, unless you you want to make it a function for `length()`.

If you want to wrap your logic for length inside a function, that would actually become a method(and not remain a property anymore), i don't have any alternative way to override that

But if you want the logic: this one

```
        if(typeof this.str[0]=='undefined')
            this.length=0;          

        else
            for (var i = 0; typeof this.str[i]!='undefined' ; i++) 
             this.length++;
```

to be called whenever the length function(property what you want to make) is called, then you must create a method for it.

So Property `length` in this case wont be possible, unless you stick to your approach

Comment: Thanks for your reply ..I want to know weather the coding is as per standards or not ? Is it good programming style or any better approach

Comment: @rajashekarthirumala.. yes it is good, if there is no option to you. but if you create a method, it would be even better style.. but then you will loose it as a property

Answer (score 1):

A string's length is not *calculated* in JavaScript. It is a constant that belongs to each string value. It can be queried using the [`.length` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length), which accesses the internally stored size of the respective string.

Just do

```
function MyString(str) {
    this.str = str;
    this.length = str.length;
}
MyString.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.str;
};
```

If you want to follow [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5.1) more closely, use

```
    Object.defineProperty(this, "length", {value: str.length});
```